# Uploadify Button in IE9 Slow to Load

Tags: jquery, uploadify, flash

I have an Uploadify Upload button that uses a custom image.  As far as I can tell, it loads quickly in every browser besides IE9, which takes many seconds.  I upgraded Flash Player but the problem persists.  Has anyone else run into this and come up with a solution?

Comment: I found the solution in another thread:
[www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9783597](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783597/ie9-loading-swf-files-takes-very-long)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with putting defer into script tag. Not sure if it will fix your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" DEFER>
```