# IE9: loading swf files takes very long

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, uploadify

When using Uploadify 2.1.4 on my (not local) server, all works fine in IE9. When moving the solution to the client's server, the loading of uploadify.swf takes exactly 60 seconds in IE9, but works fine in Chrome. IE9 displays it as "Pending". Accessing the swf directly works fine, headers show that both servers run Apache.

I've only traced one [similar incident](http://groups.google.com/group/swfupload/browse_thread/thread/f2dff7a6b1d9abf1) on uploadify forums without any solutions.

Uploadify code:

```
$("#gallery").uploadify({
            // Required Settings

            langFile : '/dataface/js/uploadify/uploadifyLang_en.js',
            swf : '/dataface/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            uploader : '/image_upload.php?e50e0dc4d157efb537b37e2ea8dc78f1=53b988fc110c01ba81a2ddceabf38ab7',

            // Options - HERE ARE ALL USEFUL OPTIONS, DON'T USE ANYTHING THAT ISN'T LISTED HERE
            'folder'          : '26',
            'createFolder'    : true,
            'auto'            : true,
            'buttonText'      : 'Vali pildid',
            'width'           : 150,
            'height'          : 30,
            'cancelImage'     : '/dataface/js/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
            'fileSizeLimit'   : 1*512, // 0,5MB
            'fileTypeDesc'    : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts'    : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'method'          : 'post',
            'multi'           : true,
            'queueID'         : 'fileQueue',
            'queueSizeLimit'  : 999,
            'removeCompleted' : true,
            'progressData'    : 'all',



            onQueueComplete: function (stats) {
                // Save the form (and thus reload)
                $('form[name="existing_products_record_form"]').submit();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you missing the classid attribute on your object element

see here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/issues/detail?id=371&can=1&q=IE9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20FixReleasedIn%20FixTargetedFor%20Modified

I had a similar problem where it would take 120s to download a 320byte swf in IE9 while IE8 and others took mere milliseconds

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me. Apparently IE makes contype request to find out content-type before actually downloading the swf file (http://at-byte.com/technology/contype-useragent-requests-internet-explorer). For some reason it takes 2 minutes to get a response to the contype request.